# Testing HTTP Hooks

Tags: http, api, hook

I am building an API, one of its feature is the use of HTTP POST Hook calls triggered on particular actions.

Without taking the time to set a locale route to be the target of the POST call I was looking for an online service showing live POST to a given URL or some other way of testing POST hooks in my code.

Any advices ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.postbin.org/

Comment: Ah, I see now. You want to see what the api will be receiving.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create and test POST requests with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) or the [Poster Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2691/)

Comment: There is also "charles" http://www.charlesproxy.com/ but i was looking for something more 'live'

Comment: I may have misunderstood this, but both of those are "live" in the sense that they show you exactly and immediately what is being POSTed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try HTTP request method same as POST,GET,PUT,DELETE at https://w3webtool.com/http-request-method with localhost (SEND BY CLIENT) and any host (SEND BY SERVER)